# Graphics Tablet - Cursor on wrong screen

Tags: graphics-tablet

I have a huion kamvas 24 pro graphics tablet with screen. I duel boot to windows when I want to use it, because huion advertises that they have no drivers for it, but I just discovered that it actually works - sort of.

It's set up as a second monitor, and when I apply the pen to it, it manipulates the cursor on the main monitor. What do I need to do to switch it to the other monitor? The "wacom tablet" configuration interface does not detect it. Do I need to edit a system file to make the kernel aware of the tablet somehow? It seems like it should be a relatively easy fix, given that the input actually works - it's just going to the wrong screen...

This is currently the ONLY reason I ever boot to windows. It would be nice to just be able to stay in linux.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be the nature of things that you can spend half a day working on a problem, then figure out how to fix it 15 minutes after you finally give up and post a question. The following page guided me to a fix:

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=125532

It's the post on the very bottom from "timotimo" back in 2016. He uses xinput to get input identifiers corresponding to the stylus and tablet. Then he uses xrandr to get output identifiers associated with his monitors. Then he uses "xinput map-to-output [input identifier] [output identifier" for the appropriate values. I had very different output from xinput and xrandr specific to my system, but was quickly able to make it work with a little trial and error.

Best thing about this solution is that it involved no installation of anything. Both tools are already installed in ubuntu.